# TinkerPop: Gremlin revisiting visited edges

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

**Sample Data:**

[image]

**Query to create sample data**

```
g.addV("Test1").property("title", "A")
g.addV("Test2").property("title", "B")
g.addV("Test3").property("title", "C")
g.addV("Test4").property("title", "D")

g.V().has("Test1", "title", "A").addE("rel").to(g.V().has("Test2", "title", "B"))
g.V().has("Test2", "title", "B").addE("rel").to(g.V().has("Test3", "title", "C"))
g.V().has("Test3", "title", "C").addE("rel").to(g.V().has("Test4", "title", "D"))
```

**Query**:

1. Find how `A` is connected to `A`

**Expected answer: Not Connected**

My Queries:

```
g.V().has("Test1", "title", "A").as("nodes")
.repeat(both().as("nodes"))
.emit(hasLabel("Test1")).hasLabel("Test1")
.limit(25)
.project("val").by(select(all, "nodes").unfold().values("title").fold())
```

Results (`limit 25`)

```
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A']}
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
```

Okay lets try `dedup`

```
g.V().has("Test1", "title", "A").as("nodes")
.repeat(both().as("nodes").dedup())
.emit(hasLabel("Test1")).hasLabel("Test1")
.project("val").by(select(all, "nodes").unfold().values("title").fold())
```

Result

```
{'val': ['A', 'B', 'A']}
```

---

There is **exactly one edge** between `A` and `B`. Then why is Gremlin traversing on the same edge? Am I writing the wrong query?

How Cypher Query behaves seems to be the correct way to be

```
MATCH p=((n:Test1)-[*]-(m:Test1)) RETURN p
```

[image]

---

**Gremlin Server version: 3.3.1**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like all you want is non-cyclic paths:

```
g.V().has("Test1", "title", "A").
  repeat(both().simplePath()).
    until(hasLabel("Test1")).
  path().
    by("title")
```

Comment: I felt `dedup` does exactly that for me. Got to try and understand `dedup` and `simplePath` difference

Comment: dedup is global for the current step, simplePath is local for the current path.