# Gremlin strategy to vertex peer sharing exactly the same neighbourhood

Tags: gremlin, traversal, amazon-neptune, neighbours

Using AWS Neptune, I need to find a traversal strategy that takes one reference vertex, and by traversing along one edge type, it finds another vertices that has exactly the same neighbors, ie. not more, not less.

```
g.V('1').as('ref_vertex').out('created').as('creations').in('created')
```

Finds vertices that also created the same things as "1", but it also scopes in vertexes (a) that created something else too, and also (b) those that did not create everything that "1" created.

```
g.V('1').as('ref_vertex')
 .out('created').as('creations').in('created')
 .not(out('created').where(neq('creations'))
```

Helps only problem (a), getting rid of persons created something extra.

How to i continue this query to skip (b) vertices from the result ?

Comment: possible duplicate: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211605/getting-vertices-that-are-connected-to-all-current-vertices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
g.V('1').aggregate('ref_vertex').
    out('created').
    sideEffect(aggregate('neighbors')).     /* get neighbors of 'ref_vertex' */
    in('created').groupCount().unfold().    /* group count in('created') by its occurrence times */
    as('candidate_shared_neighbor_cnt_pair').
    where('candidate_shared_neighbor_cnt_pair', eq('neighbors')).       /* select only the vertices have the same occurrence times as 'ref_vertex' */
        by(select(values)).
        by(unfold().count()).
    select(keys).
    where(without('ref_vertex'))
```

Comment: OK my mind has just blown up :) Thank you for your response, i need to think this through. How this technique will prevent fake peers that eg. share one single creation in common but otherwise both ref and peer created 2-2 other different things too, so they will pass through because the creation counts will be equal?

Comment: @BalazsDavidMolnar if ref -> c1, m1, m2; fake-peer -> c1, n1, n2. then 'neighbors' contains [c1, m1, m2], but in 'candidate_shared_neighbor_cnt_pair' , since fake-peer only occur once, so the value is 1, not equal to sizeof('neighbors')