# Finding Vertices that are connected to all current vertices

Tags: azure, gremlin, tinkerpop, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am fairly new to graph db's and gremlin and I am having a similar problem to others, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211605/getting-vertices-that-are-connected-to-all-current-vertices), in that I am trying to get the Resource Verticies that meet the all the Criteria of a selected Item. So for the following graph

[image]

- Item 1 should return Resource 1 & Resource 2.
- Item 2 should return Resource 2 only.

Here's a script to create the sample data:

```
g.addV("Resource").property("name", "Resource1")
g.addV("Resource").property("name", "Resource2")

g.addV("Criteria").property("name", "Criteria1")
g.addV("Criteria").property("name", "Criteria2")

g.addV("Item").property("name", "Item1")
g.addV("Item").property("name", "Item2")


g.V().has("Resource", "name", "Resource1").addE("isOf").to(g.V().has("Criteria", "name", "Criteria1"))
g.V().has("Resource", "name", "Resource2").addE("isOf").to(g.V().has("Criteria", "name", "Criteria1"))
g.V().has("Resource", "name", "Resource2").addE("isOf").to(g.V().has("Criteria", "name", "Criteria2"))

g.V().has("Item", "name", "Item1").addE("needs").to(g.V().has("Criteria", "name", "Criteria1"))
g.V().has("Item", "name", "Item2").addE("needs").to(g.V().has("Criteria", "name", "Criteria1"))
g.V().has("Item", "name", "Item2").addE("needs").to(g.V().has("Criteria", "name", "Criteria2"))
```

When I try the following, I get Resource 1 & 2 as it is looking at all related Resources to both Criteria, whereas I only want the Resources that match both Criteria (Resource 2).

```
g.V()
    .hasLabel('Item')
    .has('name', 'Item2')
    .outE('needs')
    .inV()
    .aggregate("x")
    .inE('isOf')
    .outV()
    .dedup()
```

So if I try the following, as the referenced question suggests.

```
g.V()
    .hasLabel('Item')
    .has('name', 'Item2')
    .outE('needs')
    .inV()
    .aggregate("x")
    .inE('isOf')
    .outV()
    .dedup()
    .filter(
        out("isOf")
        .where(within("x"))
        .count()
        .where(eq("x"))
        .by()
        .by(count(local)))
        .valueMap()
```

I get the following exception as the answer provided for the other question doesn't work in Azure CosmosDB graph database as [it doesn't support the gremlin Filter statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support#gremlin-steps).

> Failure in submitting query: g.V().hasLabel('Item').has('name', 'Item2').outE('needs').inV().aggregate("x").inE('isOf').outV().dedup().filter(out("isOf").where(within("x")).count().where(eq("x")).by().by(count(local))).valueMap(): "Script eval error: \r\n\nActivityId : d2eccb49-9ca5-4ac6-bfd7-b851d63662c9\nExceptionType : GraphCompileException\nExceptionMessage :\r\n\tGremlin Query Compilation Error: Unable to find any method 'filter' @ line 1, column 113.\r\n\t1 Error(s)\nSource : Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Gremlin.Core\n\tGremlinRequestId : d2eccb49-9ca5-4ac6-bfd7-b851d63662c9\n\tContext : graphcompute\n\tScope : graphparse-translate-csharpexpressionbinding\n\tGraphInterOpStatusCode : QuerySyntaxError\n\tHResult : 0x80131500\r\n"

I'm interested to know if there is a way to solve my problem with the gremlin steps MS provide in Azure CosmosDB ([these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support#gremlin-steps)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `filter` with `where`.
The query will work equally the same.